# Apache server configuration on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I would like to know how to configure Apache to do the following:

#### Configuration 1

When a user points their browser to `http://localhost/` (and gets the contents of `/var/www/index.html`) the browser redirects to `http://localhost/magento/` (and gets the contents of `/var/www/magento/index.php`)

#### Configuration 2

1. When the user enters the URL `http://localhost/magento/` the contents of the directory `/var/www/magento/index.php` are displayed but the URL changes to `http://localhost/`
2. Conversely when the user enteres `http://localhost/` in their browser the URL does not change but the contents of `/var/www/magento/` are displayed.
3. `http://localhost/foo/bar/foobar/` and all URLS of this sort display the contants of `/var/www/magento/foo/bar/foobar` instead of those of `/var/www/foo/bar/foobar`

---

I have tried defining a file called `/var/www/.htaccess`, which I am sure is
getting parsed by apache2, but I don't see any of the above happen. What
I've placed in it is:

```
RewriteRule / /magento/
```

Comment: The three things you've asked for are mutually exclusive. What is it that you _really_ are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have these lines uncommented in your http.conf (they come commented out by default):

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

This may be present for different versions of apache, uncomment if you have it.

```
#AddModule mod_rewrite.c
```

That should get the rewrite engine turned on.  Now for your rules:

In your .htaccess file (that is in your website root directory) add this line at the top:

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Now with that setup you should be turned on and enabled.  Now just fire off some rules.  In your case I think that should look like:

```
RewriteRule ^/magento$ /
```

Take a look at http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-url-rewriting-2/ for an easy to follow tutorial.

**EDIT**

Make sure to check that you allow overrides from your .htaccess files.  Find the <directory /> section in your httpd.conf and modify as follows:

```
<Directory />    
     Options FollowSymLinks    
     AllowOverride All
#    Order deny,allow
#    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Here's a good post that explains common problems with enabling mod_rewrite: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/917/Apache-and-mod_rewrite-and-htaccess

Comment: Hello, I've tried your solution, I've got rewrite.load inside /etc/apache2/mods-enabled, but when I place the .htaccess file in the root directory and move index.html and index.php to something other than index.html.bak and index.php.bak so that apache doesn't try to open them, I just get a directory lising of the server root, no redirection. And when I go to http: //localhost/magento I don't see the rewrite I was asking about.

Comment: See the edit for more stuff to check.